# Build a dist package with setuptools on python 3

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-wheel

I am making a package to connect to several cloud services as googlecloud, amazon s3 and sftp/ftp services for python apps,my intention is to publish as LGPL in Pypi.

The problem is that I am trying to make a dist package with setuptools and until now, I have no success.

I am following the tutorial in https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/
and I am executing command `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
inside of my package.

When I execute, I got

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing cloud_uploader.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to cloud_uploader.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to cloud_uploader.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to cloud_uploader.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'cloud_uploader.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'cloud_uploader.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating cloud-uploader-0.1
creating cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud
creating cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader
creating cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/Exceptions
creating cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
creating cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud_uploader.egg-info
copying files to cloud-uploader-0.1...
copying README.md -> cloud-uploader-0.1
copying setup.cfg -> cloud-uploader-0.1
copying setup.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1
copying cloud/__init__.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud
copying cloud/uploader/FileSystem.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader
copying cloud/uploader/__init__.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader
copying cloud/uploader/Exceptions/SystemExceptions.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/Exceptions
copying cloud/uploader/Exceptions/__init__.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/Exceptions
copying cloud/uploader/providers/AmazonProvider.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
copying cloud/uploader/providers/BaseProvider.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
copying cloud/uploader/providers/FtpProvider.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
copying cloud/uploader/providers/GoogleProvider.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
copying cloud/uploader/providers/SFTPProvider.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
copying cloud/uploader/providers/__init__.py -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud/uploader/providers
copying cloud_uploader.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud_uploader.egg-info
copying cloud_uploader.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud_uploader.egg-info
copying cloud_uploader.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud_uploader.egg-info
copying cloud_uploader.egg-info/requires.txt -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud_uploader.egg-info
copying cloud_uploader.egg-info/top_level.txt -> cloud-uploader-0.1/cloud_uploader.egg-info
Writing cloud-uploader-0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'cloud-uploader-0.1' (and everything under it)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

The structure of project is

```
.
├── build
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── cloud
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── uploader
│   │           ├── Exceptions
│   │           │   ├── __init__.py
│   │           │   └── SystemExceptions.py
│   │           ├── FileSystem.py
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           └── providers
│   │               ├── AmazonProvider.py
│   │               ├── BaseProvider.py
│   │               ├── FtpProvider.py
│   │               ├── GoogleProvider.py
│   │               ├── __init__.py
│   │               └── SFTPProvider.py
│   └── scripts-3.6
├── cloud
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── uploader
│       ├── configuration
│       │   ├── ConfigLoader.py
│       │   └── __pycache__
│       │       └── ConfigLoader.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── Exceptions
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── __pycache__
│       │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   │   └── SystemExceptions.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   └── SystemExceptions.py
│       ├── FileSystem.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── providers
│           ├── AmazonProvider.py
│           ├── BaseProvider.py
│           ├── FtpProvider.py
│           ├── FtpProvider.pyc
│           ├── GoogleProvider.py
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── __pycache__
│           │   ├── AmazonProvider.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── BaseProvider.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── FtpProvider.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── GoogleProvider.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   └── SFTPProvider.cpython-36.pyc
│           └── SFTPProvider.py
├── cloud_uploader.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── dist
│   └── cloud-uploader-0.1.tar.gz
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── test
```

If i try to install using pip install from the bitbutket

`pip install -e git+https://vteran@bitbucket.org/houselandbog/images-uploader@Ftp_Connection_Driver#egg=images_uploader`

I got

Errno 21 [Is a directory] and a traceback related to

Until now, the repo is private. But if some one wants to help me I am able to post it as public.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the content of setup.py and setup.cfg.

Comment: HI, @finswimmer. Here is it! setup.py https://pastebin.com/K5D2pBUd and  setup.cfg https://pastebin.com/6rAkVeVP

Answer (score 0):

@vteran93 The problem is about a path, maybe packages directories or files relatives path, check the setup module file

Comment: @vteran93 checkout this tutorial for python packages (Spanish tutorial) for understand the python packages distribution https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion8/distribucion.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `scripts` keyword argument in the `setuptools.setup` function does not contain an empty string, i.e.

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(scripts=[''])
```

would generate the error:

```
running build_scripts
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```